# insert element afer document.formName.name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, selector, validation

So i have:

```
<form name='formName'>
  <input name='name' value='Name'/>
 </form>
```

And:

```
if (document.formName.name.value == "Name")
 {
$(document.formName.name).after("<p>Please enter name!</p>");
 }
```

However, it seems jQuery doesn't select it.

I know there are nice validation plugins, but I'd like to write my own a simple as possible
I don't need to regex the values, just check if there is something filled in before you can send..

I also don't want to put in DIV's after the form field, because I have multiple forms on the same page, and want to select it per form..

Comment: It would als be OK to just make the value of the form red or the border of the input field red.. Just have no clue how to do this most efficiently..

Comment: Do it something like;
$('input[name="name"]').after('<np class="error">Please enter your name !</p>');

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.each($('form'), function() {
        var form = $(this);
        if (form.attr('name') === 'formName') {
            form.after('<p>Please enter name!</p>');
            return false;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('form[name="formName"]').length>0)  //if exists
{
$('form[name="formName"]').insertAfter($("<p>Please enter name!</p>"));
}
```